# Add jQuery Tabs using Brackets (application)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs

My Adobe CC license runs out in a month, and I don't fancy renewing for another year as I won't be able to get student rates any more...

I'm trying to switch to Brackets (open-source, made by Adobe), and I'm having a little trouble adding jQuery tabs to an html document.

I downloaded the 1.10.4 zip from here: https://jqueryui.com/download/#!

And when adding the html source from the jqueryui tabs page and then previewing, it doesn't show up as tabs... just text...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1"></div>
      <div id="tabs-2"></div>
      <div id="tabs-3"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

(i removed the sample text from the tabs)

I linked the files that downloaded using the code hinter, but i couldn't find a jquery-1.9.1.js file, so i just left that (is that where my problem lies?)

Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgot to include/copy some stylesheets / images etc.. 
Maybe it would be better to use CDN for inclusions like this:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is your code and its working http://jsfiddle.net/bBzC4/

Comment: Ok, what exactly is CDN? Does that mean that i don't actually need the file on my hard drive? Sorry - i'm kind of new to this. I'm comfortable once i get going but it's safe to say i have fairly limited knowledge of web design...

Comment: CDN is short for "Content delivery network", it means that those files are stored on the internet. This way you can reduce space used on your web-site and improve speed of the page loading since lot of the sites are already using it and users have that url probably loaded and this means they will use cached versions.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do i need to use the 1.8.3 and 1.9.2 libraries? Isn't there a newer 1.10.4 library available?

Comment: ^and how do i know which .js and .css need to used, so that i can link them? - Thanks

Comment: You just need to know which frameworks you are using .. in this case jquery-1.9.1 and jquery-ui-1.10.4 and then do the search on the google by adding CDN to query (for the UI you need to search jquery-ui-1.10.4.js and jquery-ui-1.10.4.css)

Comment: Ok, and how do i know which js frameworks i need to be using? (Not just in the case of tabs, but anything) 
Sorry... Dreamweaver would include all this for me, i'm sure it'll be better in the long run when i actually understand exactly what it is that i'm doing

Comment: Just look in the < head > section of the html and look for anything "suspicious", note that frameworks are sometimes also included in the footer (before the ending < /body > tag)

Comment: Ok, so it's all working now, annoyingly the code that i downloaded missed out the "http:", only starting with "//code.jquery...". After putting that in it fixed it. 

Now i'm having the problem of not being able to edit the CSS... In Dreamweaver, all dependent files were downloaded upon adding jquery (or at least the widgets that dreamweaver included). In Brackets, they're not.... Any ideas? 

Thanks for all of your help so far!! I'm sure this is the last thing!!

Comment: You can always override those styles, just create a local css file and put all classes you need to change in there with your customizations, then you will be able to edit them trough the dreamweaver.